# Effective data structure for both deleteMin and search by key operations

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap, stl-algorithm

I have 100 sets of A objects, each set corresponding to a query point Qi, `1 <= i <= 100`.

```
class A {
    int id;
    int distance;
    float x;
    float y;
}
```

In each iteration of my algorithm, I select one query point Qi and extract from the corresponding set the object having the minimum distance value. Then, I have to find this specific object in all 100 sets, searching with its id, and remove all those objects.

If I use a heap for each set of objects, it is cheap to extract the object with `MIN(distance)`. However, I will not be able to find the same object in other heaps searching with the id, because the heap is organized with the distance value. Further, updating the heap is expensive.

Another option I have considered is using a `map<id, (distance, x, y)>` for each set. This way searching (find operation) by id is cheap. However, extracting the element with the minimum value takes linear time (it has to examine every element in the map).

Is there any data structure that I could use that is efficient for both the operations I need?

- extract_min(distance)
- find(id)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did some formatting for you.  Please use the buttons above the edit box to format your code properly.

Comment: Not a C++ girl, so can't really contribute a meaningful answer, but sometimes for cases like this, easiest solution is two data structures: map or hashtable to lookup items by index, sorted array / heap / tree set to find the minimum item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::map` or `boost::multi_index`

Comment: Thanks, boost::multi_index did the job

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tree map.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @stakx Asking for an effective data structure and answering with a data structure is an answer. T

Comment: I know. Your answer is not wrong; it's just very short. It would be much more informative if it explained, for example, *why* a tree map would be appropriate; or you describe the most important properties and operations of a tree map; or at least link to a paper that does all that. As your answer stands, you could have posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to have two maps for each data set. The first one contains all the data items sorted by id. The second would be a `multimap` and map distance to id so that you could easily figure out what id the lowest distance corresponds to. This one would be ordered by distance to make finding the min cheap (since it would use distance as the key). You could use `map` instead of `multimap` if you know that distances will always be unique.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ncluding a map as 
suggested by many above, you
could replace your minimum heap
with a structure that has a
runtime complexity that is constant
for extract min.  Your current version
has runtime complexity of O(log_2(n))
for extract min.
Since the range of your distances is
small, you could use a "Dial array" 
algorithm.  The keys are like "counting sort".
Because you may have more than one item in
an array item, but you don't care about the
order of equal value items, you would use
a doubly linked list as the array's item
data type.  The Andrew Goldberg and Tarjan papers 
regarding faster Dijkstra's algorithms 
dicuss this in more detail.